# How to write cron expression?

Tags: cron, mule

In mule, I need to poll once in 48 hours.

I wrote the cron expression `0 0 1/48 ? * *` but it is running twice in 48 hours, i.e, once in 24 hours.

Can anybody suggest exact expression?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can notice in the cron expression you are using is you are putting 1/48 at wrong position.
The cron expression has specific place for unit of time.

Minute  Hour    Day     Month   Weekday
if you want to execute the job every 48 hours you should something like this :

```
0 */48 * * *
```

or if you want to execute the job once in 2 days then you could use something like below:

`0 0 */2 * *`

Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of cron maker.

http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `0 0 0 1/2 * ? *` to poll once every two days at 12 AM. The 3rd value from right can be used to specify that at what hour you want to poll once every two days.